# how many integers satisfy for modular aritmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How many integers $n$ are there which satisfy $1\leq n \leq 2014$ and $21n = 25 \pmod {29}$?

Comment: Have you tried solving the linear congruence?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: instead of using standard methods, this congruence is very easy to solve by simplifying the coefficients and cancelling:
$$21n\equiv25\pmod{29}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  -8n\equiv-4\pmod{29}\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
  2n\equiv1\pmod{29}$$
and so on.

Comment: +1 Nice one. The last one can be solved by using:

$$2n \equiv 1 \equiv 30 \pmod{29} \Leftrightarrow n \equiv 15 \pmod{29}$$

Comment: Since we are looking how many $n$ which satisfy $1\leq n \leq 2014$: So $2014/15=134$, thus there is 134 different $n$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$21^{-1} \equiv 18 \pmod{29}$$

Therefore:

$$18·21 n \equiv 18·25 \pmod{29} \Longrightarrow n \equiv 15 \pmod{29}$$

Comment: sorry how you compute $21^{-1}=18 (mod 29)$?

Comment: Use Bezout's Identity to solve $21x + 29y = 1$. Then $x = 21^{-1} \pmod{29}$